# generate redis dump file or json file from remote redis server

Tags: redis

I'm using rdb-tool to generate json file from Redis dump file. For example:

```
rdb --command json /opt/redis/data/master.rdb --db 8 > /opt/redis/data/latest.json
```

is there anyway that I can generate Redis json data file from remote server? something similiar to this:

```
rdb --command json --db 8 --host myhost.com --port 6378 > /opt/redis/data/latest.json
```

Thanks

Comment: I found this but not sure how reliable it is: https://github.com/delano/redis-dump

Comment: What is your use-case? Can you elaborate why you would want Redis dump in a json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.

You have to request first a dump to be generated to the remote server (with a BGSAVE command). Beware it is asynchronous, so you have to wait for the completion of the dump by checking the results of the INFO command. Then download the file on your local machine (with sftp, scp, netcat, etc ...), and finally you can run rdb-tools script locally.

Another way to do it (provided you have the memory available on your client box), is to start a slave redis-server on the client. It will automatically generate and download a dump file from the master, that you can use against rdb-tools locally.